# Is "My purse was stolen when I had been shopping" grammatical?

Tags: past-perfect, progressive-aspect, continuous-aspect

> i) My purse was stolen when I was shopping.
>
> ii) My purse was stolen when I had been shopping.

I thought that i) was grammatical and ii) ungrammatical. But yesterday I found the next sentence from *Sword & Citadel: The Second Half of 'The Book of the New Sun'*.

> Then, quite unexpectedly, **when I had been staring at them** for a long time, the shape of a peryton seemed to spring out as distinctly as if the bird's whole body had been powdered with the dust ground from diamond.

Then, is ii too grammatical?

Comment: Your second version is a bit unlikely except in a *very* contrived context that I can't be bothered to flesh out. Usually we'd say ***...after** I had been shopping* (assuming that's what we meant). But for reasons that aren't clear to me, using ***when*** rather than ***after*** in the *Sword & Citadel* cite doesn't come across as *quite* so unusual.

Comment: In the _Sword & Citadel_ example, it (the 'when') reads a bit like all that stuff happened _because_ they were staring for a long time. Could it be a hallucination?

Comment: Why not use "while"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The reason is “for a long time”. A progressive pluperfect preceded by _when_ like this requires a time phrase to work—try removing it from the S&C quote, or adding in “for an hour” in the shopping quote. _When_ + progressive means that the action was still going on (the peryton, whatever that is, appeared while the watcher was still staring, and the shopper wasn't quite planning on having finished their shopping at the time the purse was stolen). This is different from _after_, which does just fine without a specified time.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatical but have different meanings. The first implies that your purse was stolen while you were in the process of shopping, possibly from an open handbag or a supermarket trolley.

The second implies that the purse was stolen after you had finished shopping, possibly from your home or on your way home by public transport.